# Apache Storm compared to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, streaming, apache-storm

How does Storm compare to Hadoop? Hadoop seems to be the defacto standard for open-source large scale batch processing, does Storm has any advantages over hadoop? or Are they completely different?

Comment: I think the question made total sense and it's hard for me to understand how such a useful question was closed as non-constructive. The question was direct, there was no need of facts, references, etc.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Why don't you tell your opinion.

- http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/09/twitter-storm-real-time-hadoop/
- http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/08/storm-is-coming-more-details-and-plans.html

Twitter Storm has been touted as real time Hadoop. That is more a marketing take for easy consumption.

They are superficially similar since both are distributed application solutions. Apart from the typical distributed architectural elements like master/slave, zookeeper based coordination, to me comparison falls off the cliff.

Twitter is more like a pipline for processing data as it comes. The pipe is what connects various computing nodes that receive data, compute and deliver output. (There lingo is spouts and bolts) Extend this analogy to a complex pipeline wiring that can be re-engineered when required and you get Twitter Storm.

In nut shell it processes data as it comes. There is no latency.

Hadoop how ever is different in this respect primarily due to HDFS. It a solution geared to distributed storage and tolerance to outage of many scales (disks, machines, racks etc)

M/R is built to leverage data localization on HDFS to distribute computational jobs. Together, they do not provide facility for real time data processing. But that is not always a requirement when you are looking through large data. (needle in the haystack analogy)

In short, Twitter Storm is a distributed real time data processing solution. I don't think we should compare them. Twitter built it because it needed a facility to process small tweets but humungous number of them and in real time.

See: [HStreaming](http://www.hstreaming.com/) if you are compelled to compare it with some thing

Comment: +1, agree completely. Just a small note: Twitter didn't build it, they [acquired](http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/08/storm-is-coming-more-details-and-plans.html) it. BackType built it originally.

Comment: @johndodo: Thanks. I was completely unaware of it's origin.

Comment: Nice analogy with pipeline of changing topology.

Comment: As the question has been closed, I'd add my opinion as an comment: just treat Storm vs. Hadoop as *STDIN* processing vs. *File* processing. Take the word count application as an example, Stormie reads your input words from the console, while Hadooper scans words from a disk file you created yesterday. It's just both Storm and Hadoop have to go distributed when task volume becomes too large.

Comment: Basically Storm is good at everything Hadoop doesn't do (Real time computation). And Hadoop is good at everything Storm doesn't do (Persistency). The two systems are complementary, and Twitter now open-sourced [Summingbird|https://github.com/twitter/summingbird] which bridges the two...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. It really helped me out. I'm building a crawler engine and I was going with hadoop but it really seems that Storm is a more suitable choice for me.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, both of them are used for analyzing big data, but Storm is used for real time processing while Hadoop is used for batch processing.

This is a very good introduction to Storm that I found: 
[Click here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Storm)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than to be compared, they are supposed to supplement each other now having batch + real-time (pseudo-real time) processing. There is a corresponding video presentation - [Ted Dunning on Twitter's Storm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PcmbI5aC20)

Comment: Can this twitter storm architecture be duplicated in a windows environment?

Comment: Pretty much everything can be duplicated but i doubt this would have any sense to be implemented in Windows because Storm is intended for "real-time" processing.

Comment: What do you mean by "pseudo-real time", please expand.

Comment: Nothing fancy. Just wanted to point that "real" real-time software has stricter requirements including OS - "A real-time operating system (RTOS) is an operating system (OS) intended to serve real-time application requests. It must be able to process data as it comes in, typically without buffering delays. Processing time requirements (including any OS delay) are measured in tenths of seconds or shorter."(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). In that sense, Storm's real-time feature is a way to be distinguished from batch processing systems.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Storm for a while and now I've quit this really good technology for an amazing one : Spark (http://spark.apache.org) which provides developer with a unified API for batch or streaming processing (micro-batch) as well as machine learning and graph processing.

worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Storm is for Fast Data (real time) & Hadoop is for Big data(pre-existing tons of data). Storm can't process Big data but it can generate Big data as a output.

Answer (score 0):

> Apache Storm is a free and open source distributed realtime computation system. Storm makes it easy to reliably process unbounded streams of data, doing for realtime processing what Hadoop did for batch processing.

Since many sub systems exists in Hadoop ecosystem, we have to chose right sub system depending on business requirements & feasibility of a particular system.

Hadoop MapReduce is efficient for batch processing of one job at a time. This is the reason why Hadoop is being used extensively as a data warehousing tool rather than  data analysis tool.

Since the question is related to only "**Storm**" vs "**Hadoop**", have a look at [Storm use cases](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/storm/) - Financial Services, Telecom, Retail, Manufacturing, Transportation.

1. Hadoop MapReduce is best suited for batch processing.
2. Storm is a complete stream processing engine and can be used for real time data analytics with latency in sub-seconds.

Have a look at this [dezyre article](https://www.dezyre.com/article/spark-vs-hadoop-vs-storm/145) for comparison between Hadoop, Storm and Spark. It explains similarities and differences.

It can be summarized with below picture ( from `dezyre` article)

[image]