# Twitter Storm v/s Apache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

It would be great if somebody can explain me the **architectural differences** between Twitter Storm and Apache Hadoop? I am looking out for some internals stuff beyond real time v/s batch processing. As both technologies are quiet similar in terms of writing a topology for Storm or map-reduce on Hadoop, in terms of task tracker/job tracker for Hadoop and the equivalent nimbus/supervisor for Storm, in terms of Hadoop partition and equivalent shuffling (random, field etc.) on Storm etc. (Am I correct if I say that Storm uses message queues internally for transporting data between spouts/bolt which is not exactly the case with Hadoop where in there are intermediate files created and hence an I/O involved.)

EDIT:

I have gone through the question [Apache Storm compared to Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250028/twitter-storm-compared-to-hadoop?rq=1) but the accepted answer leaves me with a desire to know more than just the use case i.e. real time v/s batch processing.

Comment: The architecture of reliable systems are usually almost the same. As you pointed out, the only real difference is the strategy of storing and sending data.

Answer (score 7):

The main diffence is that Storm can do realtime processing of streams of Tupple s (incoming data) while Hadoop do batch processing with MapReduce jobs.

both of them process data in a distributed way, but with storm you can have live analitics while you will have to wait the mapreduce job to finish before playing with your results.

Answer (score 3):

Nathan Marz (Storm creator) is writing a book about [Big Data](http://www.manning.com/marz/) where he discusses how to create big data systems with Hadoop, Storm and other technologies.

The book is discussing "The Lambda Architecture". Checkout this slide by Nathan Marz himself: [Runaway complexity in Big Data... and a plan to stop it](http://www.slideshare.net/nathanmarz/runaway-complexity-in-big-data-and-a-plan-to-stop-it)

Comment: I've been waiting for too long for the book to be released.